# Remove selected row in table from Knockout observable array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Alright i have working code that removes a selected row(s) via a checkbox being checked. However i am running into the issue of enforcing that only one of the radio buttons can be checked at any given moment. My first approach is to tie a click event to the each radio button and if it gets clicked, it loops through the observable array and marks all "false." Then it simply flips the flag to true for the item that fired the event. I know this isn't the best way but my lack luster knowledge of knockout is forcing me down this path..even though this method doesn't work atm. Can anyone shed light on what i am doing wrong or how to properly wire this up?

The html for the table

```
                <table class="accountGroups information" id="tblAccountGroups">
                <tr>
                    <td width="125px;" style="font-weight: bold;">StandardAccountNo</td>
                    <td width="125px;" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Primary</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Effective Date</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">End Date</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Remove</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- ko foreach: NewAccountGroupDetails-->
                <tr id="Model.NewAccountGroupDetails[0].AccountGroupName" class="acctgrp-row">
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <input style="width: 100%;" data-bind="value: StandardAccountNo, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].StandardAccountNo'}" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="text-align:center;">
                            <input style="width:100%;" type="radio" data-bind="value: IsPrimary, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].IsPrimary'}, click: $parent.markIsPrimary" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <input style="width:125px;" class="datepicker" data-bind="value: EffectiveDate, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].EffectiveDate'}" readonly="readonly" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <input style="width:125px;" class="datepicker" data-bind="value: EndDate, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].EndDate'}" readonly="readonly" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="text-align:center;">
                            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: markedForDeletion, attr: {name: 'NewAccountGroupDetails[' + $index() + '].MarkedForDeletion'}" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </table>
```

The JS below powers the page

```
////VIEW MODEL FOR KNOCKOUT////
var Detail = function () {
    this.StandardAccountNo = ko.observable('');
    this.IsPrimary = ko.observable(false);
    this.EffectiveDate = ko.observable(formattedDate(new Date()));
    this.EndDate = ko.observable(formattedDate(new Date()));
    this.markedForDeletion = ko.observable(false);
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var rawList = '@Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.NewAccountGroupDetails))';
    this.NewAccountGroupDetails = ko.observableArray(convertJSONToKoObservableObject($.parseJSON(rawList)));
    this.NewAccountGroupDetails.push(new Detail());

    this.deleteMarkedItems = function () {
        this.NewAccountGroupDetails.remove(function (item) {
            return item.markedForDeletion();
        });
    };

    this.markIsPrimary = function () {
        for (i = 0; this.NewAccountGroupDetails().length > 0; i++) {
            this.NewAccountGroupDetails[i].IsPrimary(false);
        }
        return item.IsPrimary(true);
    };

    this.addNew = function () {
        this.NewAccountGroupDetails.push(new Detail());

        $('.datepicker').each(function (i, obj) {
            $(obj).datepicker({ changeYear: true, changeMonth: true });
        });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

function convertJSONToKoObservableObject(json) {
    var ret = [];
    $.each(json, function (i, obj) {
        var newOBJ = {};
        for (prop in obj) {
            newOBJ[prop] = ko.observable(obj[prop]);
        }
        ret.push(newOBJ);
    });

    return ret;
}
```

Once i have the page working the way i want it to, i'll look into syntax improvements such as ko mapping library for the array.

Comment: you still looking for an answer ?

Comment: yea with the undated question above

Answer (score 2):

In your view model, construct the remove button like this:

```
viewModel.remove = function (row) {
    console.log(row);
    viewModel.NewAccountGroupDetails.remove(row);
};
```

Now, the current context is passed as the first argument to any callback in knockout. Therefore, if you add a button with `data-bind="click: $parent.remove"`, it will call the `viewModel.remove` function with the row context.

```
<tr ...>
    ...
    <td>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'll get this implemented in testing soon but what about the highlighting the selected row? I am still not able to get that feature to work with an onclick event. It hits the handler but the object sent to it is the window itself..i have no idea how to use that for determining the row clicked and adding a css class to it. :( In jquery its $('blah').addClass('highlight');

Comment: I have tried the above method and it gets an error on the $parent.remove sayings its not found. If i use $root it'll pass over the window as the object but that's not what i want :(

Comment: I know why the above example doesn't work...the buttons are outside the foreach binding loop so the button is not tied to the row thus parent doesnt exist. With that in mind..how do i get it to highlight a row upon selecting one and then if they hit remove, it removes that highlighted row?

Answer (score 1):

I'd need some extra information, but let me show you an example, and give you a few advices:

First, the advices:

1. in order to convert your regular object in an object with observable properties an arrays you can use the [Knockout Mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).
2. you can omit the step of parsing the JSON. You can simply assigng the JSON to a var, like this: `var JSON=*your serialized JSON*;` (Don't forget the semicolon at the end.
3. instead of including so many code in the data-bind, like this: `NewAccountGroupDetails['+ $index() + '].EndDate`, do this calculation on the viewmodel itself, an use a computed named, for example `EndDateName`
4. your viewmodel should include a `selectedRow` observable. When the user selects the row, put the row there, and you can use a computed observable that determines if a row is the selected row or not.
5. take into account that you can bind events that invoke functions in your code, and this events carry the data associated to the DOM object that originated the event. I.e. if the users clicks a row associated to a account group detail, you'll receive it in the event.

Example for 2:

```
// Instead of:
var viewModelJson = '[{"name": "Pepe"},{"name":"Juan"}]';
var viewModel = $.parseJSON(viewModelJson);

// Do this directly:

var people = [{"name": "Pepe"},{"name":"Juan"}];
```

As 4 and 5 are not clear at once, this is a simple sample of what you want to achieve.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li data-bind="text: name, click: $root.select,
       css: {red: $data == $root.selectedPerson()}" >
    </li>
</ul>
```

NOTE that the css class `red` is applied when the condition true. And the condition is that the value bound to the current row is the same as the value in the `selectedPerson` observable.

And this is the corresponding JavaScript (remember to reference knockout mapping!!)

```
var people = [{"name": "Pepe"},{"name":"Juan"}];

var PeopleModel = function(people) {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedPerson = ko.observable();    // This will hold the selected person
    self.people = ko.mapping.fromJS(people);  // Note ko.mapping!!
    self.select = function(person) {  // event receives the current data as 1st param
        self.selectedPerson(person);
    }
    self.delete = function(person) {
        // find de index of person and remove 1 item from that index
        self.people.splice(self.people.indexOf(person),1);
    }
    return self;
};

var peopleModel = new PeopleModel(people);

ko.applyBindings(peopleModel);
```

You can [run the jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/5zgv2j34/).

If you change the click binding to invoke `$root.delete` instead of `$root.select`, you'll see the person dissapear from the list when clicking it. Of course, you can add an extra element to do so.

NOTE: you can read the docs on [click binding on knockout js site](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

And a last advice: it's much better to use Web API, or a method returning a JsonResult to recover the data directly from the server, and keep the js on a separate file.

**UPDATE**
A little bit mode code.

You can add this HTML:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: removeSelected" value="removeSelected"/>
```

And this method in the view model:

```
self.removeSelected = function() {
    if (self.selectedPerson()) {
        self.delete(self.selectedPerson());
    }
};
```

If you do so, when clicking the button, if there is a selected item, it will be removed from the list.

#### UPDATE: Another, more comple example

Here you have a more complete example, [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/n5jpztqp/), that includes the code below:

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}
.container {
    margin: 10px 0;
    border: solid 1px #ABF;
}
.container > div {
    padding: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #ABF;
    position: relative;
}
.selected {
    border: solid 1px #00A;
    color: #00A;
    background-color: #BCF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: people" class="container">
    <div data-bind="click: $root.select,
           css: {selected: $data == $root.selectedPerson()}" >
               <!-- ko text: name --><!-- /ko -->
               <input type="button" value="Remove" 
                   style="right:3px;top:2px; position:absolute;"
                   data-bind="click:$root.delete"/>
    </div>
</div>    

<div data-bind="visible: selectedPerson()" >
    <input type="button" data-bind="click: removeSelected" value="Remove Selected"/>
    <input type="button" data-bind="click: unSelect" value="Deselect"/>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: selectedPerson()" class="container">
    <div>
        Selected: <!-- ko text: selectedPerson().name --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var people = [{"name": "Pepe"},{"name":"Juan"},{"name":"Luis"},{"name":"Adolfo"}];

var PeopleModel = function(people) {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedPerson = ko.observable();    // This will hold the selected person
    self.people = ko.mapping.fromJS(people);  // Note ko.mapping!!
    self.select = function(person) { // The event receives the current data as parameter
        self.selectedPerson(person);
    };
    self.delete = function(person) {
        // find de index of person and remove (splice) it from the observable array
        self.people.splice(self.people.indexOf(person),1);
        self.selectedPerson(null);
    }
    self.removeSelected = function() {
        if (self.selectedPerson()) {
            self.delete(self.selectedPerson());
        }
    };
    self.unSelect = function() {
        self.selectedPerson(null);
    }
    return self;
};

var peopleModel = new PeopleModel(people);

ko.applyBindings(peopleModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to temporarily save the selected row when you select it

```
    function AccountGroupViewModel() {
        var viewModel = this;
        viewModel.selectedRow = null;
        // ...

        viewModel.selectRow = function (data) {
            // ...
            viewModel.selectedRow = data;
        }

        viewModel.remove = function () {
            // ...
            if (viewModel.selectedRow != null) {
                this.NewAccountGroupDetails.remove(viewModel.selectedRow);
            }
        }
    }
```